# Output Command Line (.Bat FILE) show in textbox with c#

Tags: c#, textbox

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python27\ToolArtworkEmoji.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        textbox1.Text = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Why code not active. It not show command in textbox.
Can I help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by _not active_? Where is textbox exactly? What is in the this `.bat` file?

Comment: Does this work if you call an .exe ?

Comment: I want run .bat file. You can help me to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the output in your `proc_OutputDataReceived` handler, and not via `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`

In other words, put something like

```
textbox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{textbox1.Text=e.Data;}));
```

in the `proc_OutputDataReceived` handler (e is a DataReceivedEventArgs argument)

Answer (score 0):

```
            private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python27\ToolArtworkEmoji.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    {

    private void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        tblog.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { tblog.Text = e.Data; }));
    }
```

E had Edited. And it doesn't active. Textbox not show anything.